# Elasticsearch : Search with special character Open & Close parentheses

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Hi I am trying to search a word which has these characters in it '(' , ')' in elastic search. I am not able to get expected result.

This is the query I am using

```
{
"query": {
    "query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "name",
        "query" : "\\(Pas\\)ta\""
    }
}}
```

In the results I am getting records with "PASTORS" , "PAST", "PASCAL", "PASSION" first.  **I want to get name 'Pizza & (Pas)ta' in the first record in the search result as it is the best match**.

Here is the analyzer for the name field in the schema

```
"analysis": {
  "filter": {
    "autocomplete_filter": {
      "type": "edge_ngram",
      "min_gram": "1",
      "max_gram": "20"
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "autocomplete_filter"
      ]
    }
  }

 "name": {
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "type": "string"
   },
```

Please help me to fix this, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `standard` tokenizer which is removing `(` and `)` from the tokens generated. Instead of getting token `(pas)ta` one of the token generated is `pasta` and hence you are not getting match for `(pas)ta`.

Instead of using `standard` tokenizer you can use `whitespace` tokenizer which will retain all the special characters in the name. Change analyzer definition to below:

```
  "analyzer": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "autocomplete_filter"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! @Nishant Saini Is there any other side effects if I change tokenizer to whitespace from standard, Is there any way to pass analyzer in query without changing schema

Comment: Both are different `whitespace` tokenize based on space whereas `standard` tokenize provides grammar based tokenization. You can pass analyzer in query but that won't help as it will applied to the input string of query

Comment: I canged tokenizer to Whitespace,  Is it because of ""search_analyzer": "standard" , If so how to fix that